# Migrate .Net/C# projects wit OdbcConnection to SqlConnection with Informix DB

Tags: .net, ado.net, odbc, informix, sqlconnection

we have tons of old C#-code using OdbcConnection with Informix DB. The code use types like DbConnection, DbCommand, DbParameter, where parameter binding done nameless with ? symbol everywhere in code. Now I need to modernize that code (alone, all previos developers gone already) and use SqlConnection instead of OdbcConnection.

Is that possible without caveats?
Is it possible, as alternative, to have second opened connection (SqlConnection) together with opened OdbcConnection? What about nested/parallel transactions?

Again, the question is specific to Informix DB, not MS SqlServer.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The MS SQL .NET Provider (which gives you SqlConnection, SQLCommand, etc) will not be able to connect to an Informix database. This provider is just for SQL Server, you can't use it against any other database.

To connect .NET applications with Informix you need a 'suitable' .NET Provider.
The ODBC .NET Data Provider acts a bridge between .NET and any ODBC Driver. You current code appears to use it (eg. DbConnection = OdbcConnection()).

The ODBC .NET Provider is still available in latest versions of .NET (including .NET Core) so you should be able to keep using it with any current Informix ODBC driver (like 4.50.FC7).

Another (better) option would be to use the 'Informix .NET Provider' (included in the same install package as the Informix ODBC driver, 'Informix Client SDK'). This .NET Provider is specific to Informix databases and has supports more Informix features than the 'generic' ODBC .NET Provider.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=guide-overview-informix-net-provider

In terms of 'nested' transactions, Informix support the SAVEPOINT SQL statement to split complex transactions into smaller units. You can use that method to do 'nested' transactions (I think SQLServer does the same)

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-savepoint-statement

Comment: Thanks @jsagrera, the whole point is not simply to modernize a used driver, but I strongly need some features not available in OdbcConnection, but in SqlConnection - **table valued parameters (TVP)**. Somebody on internet mentioned, SqlConnection over Microsoft Sql Client is not limited to MsSqlServer only, others suggest to use Informix with Ado.Net as bridge to SqlConnection - but nobody provides examples. What can be a real solutions without creepy workarounds, like pass as value records as text with the same type spec cast per value record - huge performance and memory overhead?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can use a SQLConnection to connect to anything other than SQLServer.  That's why MS created the ODBC .NET Provider (and the OLEDB .NET one), to allow .NET to connect to databases which  lacked a proper .NET Provider.
The IBM Data Server .NET Provider (another provider developed by IBM which works with against Informix databases) has a IfxBulkCopy/Db2BulkCopy class which can be used to speed up updates. (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=adonet-data-server-provider-net), maybe that's an option, but I will always go with the 'native' Informix CSDK one.

Comment: Thank you, @jsagrera. MS ODBC .NET Provider is currently used, and this one does not have TVP support. Now, we have an (parametrized) option to use IBM .Net Provider. It is much faster, but some pieces of code (luckily small amount) must be modified. I don't need an UPDATE. What I need is an SELECT with feature of TVP, because of there are many parameters (it is like a SET), but without TVP the line will be much longer just because Informix require an exact type per parameter entry, elsewise it will try to cast all of them to first parameter and produce an error.